# How to draw arbitrary interactive shapes at any position on the screen using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, shapes, interactive

There is a need to draw several polygons of different shapes and place them close to each other in certain places on the screen. In this case, it is necessary to be able to make each of the figures interactive, i.e. have their own properties and actions when tapped. In this case, the figures must be on a transparent layer and be able to overlap each other. Is that possible?

For example i need draw square 300x300, but each of the four sides must be independent line with own name and Tap Action: Line1-0:0-300:0, Line2-300:0-300:300, Line3-300:300-0:300 and Line4-0:300-0:0. If you add lines one by one to the stacklayout, together they do not form a square. I tried to use absolutelayout, but as a result everything is drawn as it should, but I can only press Line4, because it overrides all others.

Even if straight lines can be constrained with AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds, this will not always work with more complex shapes, including diagonals. for example, a diagonal overlaps all the space equal to its width and height.

Comment: use SkiaSharp or XF Shapes

Answer (score 2):

I use **Xamarin.Forms Shapes** to create polygons.

Use **tap gesture recognizer** to add click actions.

Here is the xaml code:

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Polygon Points="0 48, 0 144, 96 150, 100 0"
     Fill="Blue"
     Stroke="Red"
     StrokeThickness="3" >
        <Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
             />
        </Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
    </Polygon>
</StackLayout>
```

For more information please check [Xamarin.Forms Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/polygon) and [tap gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap)

Comment: Thanks, but i found this way earlier and with this way i cant do what i need. For example i need draw square 300x300, but each of the four sides must be independent line with own name and Tap Action: Line1-0:0-300:0, Line2-300:0-300:300, Line3-300:300-0:300 and Line4-0:300-0:0. If you add lines one by one to the stacklayout, together they do not form a square. I tried to use absolutelayout, but as a result everything is drawn as it should, but I can only press Line4, because it overrides all others.

Comment: Even if straight lines can be constrained with AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds, this will not always work with more complex shapes, including diagonals. for example, a diagonal overlaps all the space equal to its width and height.